# Localized week days on android

Tags: android, localization

I'm trying to implement something like scheduling in my application, so I need to get names of all the day in a week and show it to user. It is simple: i can just make an enum with all the days and use it, but the localization problem shows up. The list will have english lables always. Is there a way to localize the days of week simply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a function that gets as a parameter one of these enums, and returns a resource string.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the built-in mechanism?
[See the doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).